# SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table] ON not working

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to insert some records where I specify the Id, for the purpose of migrating data where I would like to maintain the integrity of existing relationships.

To do this I ran this command directly in SSMS on the table:

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [CRMTItem] ON;
```

Yet, when I insert an item from C# with Id of 1, the Id is still incrementing from around 850.

I deleted the entities from EDMX and updated again from DB but with the same result.

Here is my insert code, where as you can see I am ensuring that the Id is indeed 1 before inserting, yet this just gets ignored..

```
var crmtItem = new CRMTItem();

crmtItem.Id = adv.PrimaryId;
crmtItem.ProjectTitle = adv.ProjectTitle;
crmtItem.CreatedByUser = (adv.CreatedBy == null) ? (Guid?)null : new Guid(adv.CreatedBy);
crmtItem.Opportunity = (adv.Opportunity == null) ? (Guid?)null : new Guid(adv.Opportunity);
crmtItem.BidNoBid = adv.Bnb;
crmtItem.SPUrl = adv.SPUrl;
crmtItem.BnbId = (adv.BnbId == null) ? (Guid?)null : new Guid(adv.BnbId);
crmtItem.Stage = adv.ProjectStage;
crmtItem.Confidential = adv.Confidential;
crmtItem.OpportunityStatus = adv.OpportunityStatus;
crmtItem.OpportunityNumber = adv.OpportunityNumber;
crmtItem.CRMTNumber = adv.CrmtNumber;
crmtItem.ProjectNumber = adv.ProjectNumber;
crmtItem.Sector = adv.Sector;
crmtItem.Service = adv.Service;
crmtItem.CreatedDate = adv.CreatedDate;
crmtItem.Archive = adv.Archive;
crmtItem.ProjectManager = adv.ProjectManager;
crmtItem.WorkTeam = adv.WorkTeam;
crmtItem.Custodian = adv.Custodian;

db.CRMTItems.Add(crmtItem);

if (adv.PrimaryId == 1 || adv.PrimaryId == 2 || adv.PrimaryId == 3)
{
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

I also tried adding this line before inserting the item

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[CRMTItem] ON");
```

But it still doesn't work.

Based on another SO question I found, I tried this next:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[CRMTItem] ON");
db.CRMTItems.Add(crmtItem);

if (adv.PrimaryId == 1)
{
    await db.SaveChangesAsync();
}
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[CRMTItem] OFF");
transaction.Commit();
```

And now I get an error

> Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'CRMTItem' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Am i missing something? Why must it be so difficult to control my own data? If I can't achieve this, I will be forced to creat a temporary column in my table just to store the id from the original (CDS) table, which is absolutely ridiculous, after all it is **MY DATA**, why can't I choose the value of the columns!?!?!

Comment: You cannot always enable identity if there's already data in your table because it might not fit the increment pattern. Also, you only need to enable identity once. So why not run it on the rdbms from the get go?

Comment: I suggest you better use queries in Sql Server directly.  You can write program to generate sql statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you generate your model from database - Entity Framework will map all identity columns to model properties with `StoreGeneratedPattern.Identity`. In your case, such property is `crmtItem.Id` as I understand. When you insert `crmItem` - Entity Framework will ignore value you set for identity property (if you set any), because it knows this value is provided by database, so it knows if it tries to provide such value in insert statement - database will return an error.

Entity Framework has no knowledge of `IDENTITY_INSERT`, so it will always behave according to `StoreGeneratedPattern` metadata of target model property. If it's `Identity` or `Computed` - it will not provide value for it in insert, whatever you do. If it's set to `None` - then it will provide a value (no matter what).

So for your case you need to set this attribute to `None` in EDMX designer for target property (`CRMTItem.Id`). Of course after doing that - you will have to always provide this value while inserting.

Another part of the problem, with `IDENTITY_INSERT` being not respected, you already solved but still worth some explanation. This setting is session-scoped, so when you just execute it in SSMS and then try to insert from your application - it has no effect: SSMS and your application are in different sessions.

When you just do:

```
db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[CRMTItem] ON");
```

This still executes in separate session, not in the same your `SaveChanges` will execute. So to execute both `IDENTITY_INSERT` and `SaveChanges` in the same session - you need to wrap them in transaction, as you already figured out.