# Identity Insert Not Working After Visual Studio Upgrade

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, entity-framework

Using SQL Server 2017, and Entityframework.dll/EntityframeworkSqlServer.dll version 6.0.0.0, the following code used to run absolutely fine:

```
using (var transaction = connect.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    connect.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Consignment] ON");
    connect.SaveChanges();
    connect.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Consignment] OFF");
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Since then, I have upgraded Visual Studio to version 16.3.10 (the latest version), and today, on running SaveChanges(), I am getting the following error:

*Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column*.

I have carefully checked that the value for the identity column (an integer) has been provided, that I can run the SQL command in SSMS, and as far as I know, the only thing that has changed since yesterday is the Visual Studio version. Can anyone think of any way that changing the Visual Studio version could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was nothing to do with the Visual Studio version - it was per this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49126424/1649135 .